# How to Remove '-None-' option from Select List Field?

Tags: 7, files

How can I remove the default option `-None-` in the Select list?
It should not be an option in my select list.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Edit the filed and make one of the option as default value in the select list and Make it required field.

Comment: It's not workking :( I have already set one option as default value but the -None- option is still there

Comment: @Charm - What is the filed type for the select list? Is it List(text) or NOdereference? and make it required field

Comment: The field type is List(text)

Answer (score 0):

If you make the field required None option will go away.. If want to remove none option for optional field follow below solution..

You can override the [theme_options_none](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!modules!options!options.module/function/theme_options_none/7) theme function. Follow below example. If you want to replace "- None -" with "SOME TEXT" everywhere, this theme implementation should do the trick:

```
function MYTHEMENAME_options_none($variables) {
  return t('SOME TEXT');
}
```

Place this function in your theme's template.php.